# issue getting dynamic Config parameter in Grails taglib

Tags: grails, config

I have a dynamic config parameter I want to get like:

```
    String srcProperty = "${attrs ['src']}.audio" + ((attrs['locale'])? "_${attrs['locale']}" : '')

    assert srcProperty == "prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting.audio"
```

where my config has:

```
prompt{
    welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting {
        audio = "/en/someFileName.wav"
        txt = "Text alternative for /en/someFileName.wav"
        audio_es = "/es/promptFileName.wav"
        txt_es = "Texto alternativo para /es/someFileName.wav"
    }
}
```

While this works fine:

```
String audio = "${config.prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting.audio}"
```

and:
        assert "${config.prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting.audio}" == "/en/someFileName.wav"

I can not get this to work:

```
String audio = config.getProperty("prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting.audio")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: This was REALLY tough, but here is what I found that worked to get a dynamic property:

```
String audio = srcProperty.tokenize( '.' ).inject( config ) { cfg, pr -> cfg[ pr ] }
```

I blogged about it:
http://www.baselogic.com/blog/development/grails-groovy-development/configslurper-with-dynamic-property-name-from-configurationholder-config-object

Answer (score 2):

They're not stored flat like that, they're stored hierarchically. "config.prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting.audio" is a shorthand to get "prompt" from config, then "welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting" from that, then "audio" from that. If you want to use dot notation just flatten the config:

```
String audio = config.flatten().getProperty("prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting.audio")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myconfig.groovy` in classpath:

```
    prompt{
     welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting {
      audio = "/en/someFileName.wav"
      txt = "Text alternative for /en/someFileName.wav"
      audio_es = "/es/promptFileName.wav"
      txt_es = "Texto alternativo para /es/someFileName.wav"
     }
    }
```

We can get properties constructing their names dynamically:

```
def myconfig = this.class.getResource("/myconfig.groovy")
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(myconfig)

def dynamic = "welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting"
def dynamic2 = "audio"
def locale = "es"

assert config.prompt[dynamic].audio == "/en/someFileName.wav"
assert config.prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting[dynamic2] == "/en/someFileName.wav"
assert config.prompt.welcomeMessageOverrideGreeting["${dynamic2}_${locale}"] == "/es/promptFileName.wav"
assert config.prompt[dynamic]["${dynamic2}_${locale}"] == "/es/promptFileName.wav"
```