# How Can I Use Config Entries with Dots When Parsing with XmlSlurper

Tags: grails, groovy, xmlslurper

I'm trying to use a groovy Config entry to parse an xml file with XmlSlurper.

Here's the Config file:

```
sample {
    xml {
        frompath = "Email.From"
    }
}
```

Here's the XML

```
<xml>
    <Email>
        <From>
            <Address>foo@bar.com</Address>
            <Alias>Foo Bar</Alias>
        </From>
    <Email>
</xml>
```

This is what I tried initially:

```
XmlSlurper slurper = new XmlSlurper()

def record = slurper.parseText((new File("myfile.xml")).text)

def emailFrom = record?."${grailsApplication.config.sample.xml.frompath}".Address.text()
```

This doesn't work because XmlSlurper allows one to use special characters in path names as long as they're surrounded by quotes, so the app is translating this as:

```
def emailFrom = record?."Email.From".Address.text()
```

and not

```
def emailFrom = record?.Email.From.Address.text()
```

I tried setting the frompath property to be `"Email"."From"`  and then `'"Email"."From"'`.  I tried tokenizing the property in the middle of the parse statement (don't ask.)

Can someone please point me towards some resources to find out if/how I can do this?

I feel like this [issue getting dynamic Config parameter in Grails taglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655794/issue-getting-dynamic-config-parameter-in-grails-taglib) and this https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/grails-injecting-config-parameters/ may have whispers of a solution, but I need fresh eyes to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in [issue getting dynamic Config parameter in Grails taglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655794/issue-getting-dynamic-config-parameter-in-grails-taglib) is a proper way to deref down such a path.  E.g.

```
def emailFrom = 'Email.From'.tokenize('.').inject(record){ r,it -> r."$it" }
def emailFromAddress = emailFrom.Address.text()
```

If your path there can get complex and you rather go with the potentially more dangerous way, you could also use `Eval`.  E.g.

```
def path = "a[0].b.c"
def map = [a:[[b:[c:666]]]] // dummy map, same as xmlslurper
assert Eval.x(map, "x.$path") == 666
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I thought injection would figure into it.  I updated the example, is it possible for you help me with that second level?

Comment: to apply above code for your example you would pass `record` instead of `map`. the path should be obvious.  the result from the inject would be `record.Email.From` then and from there you can add your `Address.text()` (if that is a given).  otherwise i might have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: NO!  I was being dim and missing what the end object would be - I printed out path after the injection and couldn't figure out why it was just my split Config property.  This works, thanks for your time!